# SFTP with Dolphin hangs on "Sending login information"

Tags: 20.04, sftp

As the title says, when I try to login to my SFTP server with Dolphin, it just keeps "Sending login information". I am not sure if it is Dolphin or some incorrect configuration on the FTP server. Looking for some advice on what might be causing this or where to look.

Ubuntu 20.04, both on personal computer and the VPS I am using.
I have opened the port with `ufw`
I have checked that I am using the correct port
I have a user set up
I have double checked all the information in Dolphin that it is correct.
Using `vsftpd` on the server

I am kind of stuck and don't know what it wrong. I would appreciate any advice on what I can check to see what is wrong.

Comment: SFTP is not FTPS.